# Playing audio in the background when using a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, avaudiosession

So I´ve don all the preliminary steps of setting the `audioSession sharedInstance` category, and activated playing audio in the background in the info.plist file

However I am using an UIWebView to display YouTube, and even thought background playing is 
supported, pressing the home button the audio stops. Is this cause YouTube uses some built in player? cause when I play an video my tab bar controller disappears.

Is there a way of having it continue playing the youtube videos in background?